# Blazor list of data erroring on return

Tags: c#, blazor

Im currently trying to make a list of data to display in a for loop on my blazor website. Everything else on the page is written right i just cannot get the return right for the service method.

```
public Task<List<FirstAider>> GetFirstAidersAsync()
        {
            List<FirstAider> f = new List<FirstAider>
            {
                new FirstAider { Name = "First Aider 1", EmailAddress = "FirstAider1@Email.com", Telephone = "01101000 01101001 00001101 00001010" },
                new FirstAider { Name = "First Aider 2", EmailAddress = "FirstAider2@Email.com", Telephone = "01101000 01101001 00001101 00001010" },
                new FirstAider { Name = "First Aider 3", EmailAddress = "FirstAider3@Email.com", Telephone = "01101000 01101001 00001101 00001010" }
            };

            return f.ToArray();
        }
```

I have attached the issue below but i have had to scribble out work project file names unfortunately so sorry for the inconvenience.

It's erroring on the f.ToArray();

[VS Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j39Az.png)

Comment: Please do not post your error as a picture but use quotes. You can remove anything you want from a text instead of scribbling things out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method has a return type of `Task<List<FirstAider>>` but you are returing an array `Array<FirstAider>`. The method does not need to return a task or be async since it does not `await` any `async` operations. Change the return type to `Array<FirstAider>` to fix the error.

Alternatively if you need the method to return a task you could do the following

```cs
public Task<List<FirstAider>> GetFirstAidersAsync()
{
    List<FirstAider> f = new List<FirstAider>
    {
        new FirstAider { Name = "First Aider 1", EmailAddress = "FirstAider1@Email.com", Telephone = "01101000 01101001 00001101 00001010" },
        new FirstAider { Name = "First Aider 2", EmailAddress = "FirstAider2@Email.com", Telephone = "01101000 01101001 00001101 00001010" },
        new FirstAider { Name = "First Aider 3", EmailAddress = "FirstAider3@Email.com", Telephone = "01101000 01101001 00001101 00001010" }
    };

    return Task.FromResult(f);
}
```

More information about [Task.FromResult here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.8)